# File extension shows in BASH but not in Finder

Tags: macos, finder, bash, file-extensions

I created a text file with a specific extension:

Vendor_0408_Product_3008.idc

It displays in finder link this:

[image]

and BASH like this:

```
-rw-r--r--@  1 raven  staff    1903 Feb 19 10:31 Vendor_0408_Product_3008.idc.rtf
```

with a .rtf extension.  In Finder, I went to preferences/advanced and made sure that "Show all filename extensions" is checked:

[image]

But it still does not display the extension?!

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure the file's own metadata is not set to hide the file extension. Right-click or control-click the file in Finder and check the setting in the "Name and Extension" area.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the file in Finder and select "Get Info" <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.
2. Click on the "Name & Extension" option in the Get Info window.
3. Uncheck the "Hide Extension" option.